Trouble in Insert MySql Workbench
Only createAt, updateAt and the registration ID are inserted - the 'email' and 'password' fields are empty, giving insert in the other fields and not in the two:

Executing (default): INSERT INTO 'Usuarios_teste' ('id', 'createdAt', 'updatedAt') VALUES (DEFAULT,?,?);

LoginModel.js:
const {
  Model,
  DataTypes
} = require('sequelize');
const validator = require('validator');
const bcryptjs = require('bcryptjs');
const sequelize = require('../config/database');


class Login extends Model {
  constructor(body) {
    super();
    this.body = body;
    this.errors = [];
    this.user = null;
  }

  async login() {
    this.valida();
    if (this.errors.length > 0) return;
    this.user = await Login.findOne({
      where: {
        email: this.body.email
      }
    });



    if (!this.user) {
      this.errors.push('Usuário não existe.');
      return;
    }

    if (!bcryptjs.compareSync(this.body.password, this.user.password)) {
      this.error.push('Senha inválida');
      this.user = null;
      return;
    }
  }

  async register() {
    this.valida();
    if (this.errors.length > 0) return;

    await this.userExists();

    if (this.errors.length > 0) return;

    if (this.user) return;

    const salt = bcryptjs.genSaltSync();
    this.body.password = bcryptjs.hashSync(this.body.password, salt);


    try {
      this.user = await Login.create({
        email: this.body.email,
        password: this.body.password
      });
    } catch (e) {
      console.error("Erro ao criar novo usuário: ", error);
      this.errors.push("Erro ao criar novo usuário.")
    }
  }
  //Valição pra conferir se o usuário já existe
  async userExists() {
    this.user = await Login.findOne({
      where: {
        email: this.body.email
      }
    });
    if (this.user) this.errors.push('Usuário já existe.')

  }

  valida() {
    this.cleanUp();

    // **Validação de campos**
    // O email precisa ser válido
    if (!validator.isEmail(this.body.email)) this.errors.push('E-mail Inválido');
    // A senha precisa ter entre 5 a 15 caracteres
    if (this.body.password.length < 5 || this.body.password.length > 15) {
      this.errors.push('A senha precisa ter entre 5 e 15 caracteres.')
    }
  }

  cleanUp() {
    for (const key in this.body) {
      if (typeof this.body[key] !== 'string') {
        this.body[key] = '';
      }
    }

    this.body = {
      email: this.body.email,
      password: this.body.password
    };
  }
}

Login.init({
  id: {
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    primaryKey: true,
    autoIncrement: true
  },
  email: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    allowNull: true
  },
  password: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    allowNull: true
  }
}, {
  sequelize,
  modelName: 'Login',
  tableName: 'Usuarios_teste'
});

//Cria o novo usuário apenas se ele não existir.
(async() => {
  try {
    await sequelize.sync();
    console.log("Modelo sincronizado com o banco de dados.");
  } catch (e) {
    console.error("Erro ao sincronizar o modelo com o banco de dados: ", e);
  }

})();

module.exports = Login;

